# pip: Install error with python2.7 on ec2 AMI

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pip

After installing pip with get-pip.py

```
 wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
 python get-pip.py
```

I get this error when I try to check the installation with `pip -V`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 637, in _build_master
return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 650, in _build_from_requirements
dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==6.1.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

However this works with python2.6.

Is there any reason why this happens that I am missing?

### Edit:

I am working with Amazon Linux AMI release 2016.03 which I guess is based on some RedHat distro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing virtualenv for manage your versions independently:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

Create the virtual environment

```
virtualenv newvenv
```

Run your new environment

```
source newvenv/bin/activate
```

Finally

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Comment: `apt-get` is not the package manager on Amazon AMI images, and it seems `virtualenv` package does not exist in repositories

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have an Ubuntu image. You need to remove the system pip version before installing the new one.

Do a apt-get remove python-pip before your commands and you will have a proper pip installed.

For python3: apt-get remove python3-pip

Same may apply for CentOS based onesbut you will have to do the same with yum instead of apt-get